# High dimensional "eigenvector"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I have come across an oddity in the solution to a problem and I am unsure with how to proceed.

For an $n\times n$ (symmetric and real-valued, usually poorly conditioned and low-rank) matrix $A$, and an $n\times m$ matrix $B$ (with $m \leq n$), and a scalar $c \neq 0$, the solution comes where:$$AB = cB$$
If $B$ were a vector, this would be a straightforward eigenvalue problem. However, $B$ is in this case a tall skinny matrix.

My intuition says that each column of $B$ must be an eigenvector of $M$ associated with the eigenvalue $c$. But as far as I can tell the only repeated eigenvalue of $M$ is $0$. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Since $AB e_k = c B e_k$ each non zero column is an eigenvaector of $A$ corresponding to $c$. What is the rank of $B$?

Comment: It looks almost like a generalized eigenvalue problem. Very often in control systems we are required to use pseudo-inverses for $B$ in order to solve it, but there are systems that do not admit such a procedure. I'll follow the post as I am interested.

Comment: @copper.hat $B$ should be full-rank (rank $m$)

Comment: @Basco I should clarify that $M$ is known but $B$ and $c$ are unknown. $c$ is determined by $B$.

Comment: Then if $m>1$ and $c \neq 0$ you have a contradiction.

Comment: @copper.hat That's what I was afraid of. Thanks

Comment: Then the problem is actually interesting as the eigenvectors span a larger space. Check out the multiplicity of c to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed the case that $AB = cB$ means that every column of $B$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with eigenvalue $c$. Indeed, if $B_1,\dots,B_n$ denote the columns of $B$, then we have
$$
AB = cB \implies A[B_1 \ \ \cdots \ \ B_n] = c[B_1 \ \ \cdots \ \ B_n] \implies
 \\ 
[AB_1 \ \ \cdots \ \ AB_n] = [cB_1 \ \ \cdots \ \ cB_n].
$$
The column span of $B$ must be a subspace of the eigenspace associated with $c$, so the rank of $B$ is at most equal to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $c$.